# Export data from Powerapps to Excel

Tags: powerapps

I have a table with data in my Power apps application and I would like to export this table to an excel sheet. Can you anyone help for this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a pure-native way to do it, but it is possible by stringing some things together.  Check this post:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/user/export-data-excel

Comment: The link is about Model driven PowerApps, OP is asking about Canvas apps

Comment: Doesn't matter, neither support native export of data, AFAIK.